# User keeps posting the same (rejected) example

Tags: support, documentation

The user is constantly ignoring the feedbacks sent by different users upon rejection:

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/14204
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/12109
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/12340

He keeps posting the same example that could eventually be approved by less experienced developers (in fact, https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/14204 was 50% approved and rejected).

Any recommended way to handle similar cases?

Comment: Your second example is not from the same user as the other two.

Comment: @animuson thanks, I've fixed the link

Comment: Does Documentation have the same kind of temporary suggested edit ban that Stack Overflow proper does? On SO, moderators could manually ban someone from suggesting edits like this if the system didn't do so first, but I don't yet have access to the moderation tools to see if this is the same over there.

Comment: No wonder, Documentation is a gold mine now. If you get something approved in tags like Git, you have an influx of reps for good.

Comment: Found this again in tkinter: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/136736 and http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/136738